# logrotate not compressing files as expected

Tags: linux, logs, busybox, logrotate

With the logrotate config. below I was expecting the program to start compressing log files after creating the first backup file.  Instead I am seeing this:

```
[root@host ~]# ll /var/log
total 1.2M
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Aug 31 13:29 ./
drwxrwxr-x 7 1000 1000 4.0K Aug 29 01:49 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  289 Aug 29 02:11 auth.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  382 Aug 31 00:59 cron.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  41K Aug 31 14:16 messages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 201K Aug 31 13:26 messages.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 201K Aug 30 23:11 messages.0.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  88K Aug 31 00:59 messages.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  38K Aug 31 14:16 user.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 201K Aug 31 13:29 user.log.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 201K Aug 30 23:12 user.log.0.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  89K Aug 31 01:02 user.log.1

[root@host ~]# cat /etc/logrotate.conf
compress

include /etc/logrotate.d

/var/log/* {
        rotate 7
        daily
    delaycompress
        missingok
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                /usr/bin/killall -HUP syslogd
        endscript
}
```

The target system is BusyBox v1.20.2.

Perhaps the problem is that I've specified to rotate all logs under /var/log, instead of naming them each explicitly?  I would prefer to be able to just say rotate all logs under /var/log however and have it work as expected.

Comment: you probably have rules in `/etc/logrotate.d/*` that conflict.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I have no files in that directory, onlt the single config. file above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `/var/log/*` is too wide and so matches previously 
rotated files and rotates them again.  You either need to specify a
more explicit list, or a more restricted wildcard pattern, or move
old logs into a new dir so they wont be mistaken. I would replace, for example,

```
/var/log/* { ... }
```

by

```
/var/log/*.log /var/log/messages { ... }
```